# How can I use telegram-js to share my phone number with a bot?

Tags: telegram

How to "share your number phone with this bot" with telegram-js?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6QmO.png)
i want to use libra telegram (npm) to click "share",  i try to sendMessage but it's not work
ex:

const client = new TelegramClient(new StringSession(sessionData), Number(apiId), apiHash );

await client.connect();
await client.sendMessage(`@${BotId}`, { message:me.numberPhone })